# When combining number in Parchesse

Tags: parcheesi

May I use a 6+4 in substitution of a double 5 to enter two pieces into play in Parchessi? Since I may use any combination which adds up to five to enter one piece and I am allowed to enter two pieces with a double 5, the rules been vague in this, It seems only logical that it may be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

No. Each die is used in toto of itself. You cannot re-combine the pips in other combinations. As for the special case of entering, [the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi) are clear on this.

> Pieces may only leave the nest with a roll of a five on a single die or the sum of the dice. A double five can be used to move two pieces from the nest simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. As the rule stated: "...the sum of the dice." It is acceptable a 4-1 or a 3-2; to enter one piece. Therefore, it is the same math, a 6-4 to enter two pieces. Isn't it?

Comment: You can use one of the dice or both, but not part of a die (whether you add that part to the other die or not). A 6-4 allows one pawn to move 6 and the other 4, or one pawn to move 10. It won't allow one pawn to move 5, nor two pawns to move 5 each.

Comment: The sum may not me multiples of five to move peices from the nest. it may only be five.